# Send email to New Campaign members owner users, when Parent reaches some condition

Tags: email, custom-button

Lets say i have a Campaign with 5 campaign members(leads). I wanted to send the owners of all NEW leads owner an email saying x number of leads have been assigned to you today.

Can i do this using custom button with javascript? till now i have tried workflow based email alert but there i can't calculate number of new leads assigned to each owner....also i wanted to send only one email per owner.

Anybody know any trick, how to do this

Comment: Yes, there are a few ways you can accomplish this, including at least one way you can do this with the Process Builder (using a Flow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you can write apex class for this, create a batch job which runs daily, categorize leads by owner name created today, so you can send one email containing data about leads assigned to him.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah coding was last option,.....I was looking for some trick